# Preconnect domain for all images in page, not just first image

Tags: performance, browsers, connections, rel-dns-prefetch, link-prefetching

I use leaflet to display a map made of about 12 maptiles, that come from 4 Stamen subdomains, only differing with  `-a`, `-b`, `-c` and `-d` middle part endings : `stamen-tiles-a.a.ssl.fastly.net` etc

So as to prefetch the DNS and preconnect, i use `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://stamen-tiles-a.a.ssl.fastly.net">` for `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` sub-domains.

When looking at the network cascade on webpagetest.com, i see that the preconnect is done in advance for the 4 domains, and is then used for the first map tiles, but is not used for *some* of the last map tiles, which require new DNS fetches and connections.

See relevant part of connect cascade  : preconnect on each 4 domains + 1st set of 4 images + 2nd set of 4 images
[image: waterfall for last tiles]

I've also tried with `rel="dns-prefetch"` and the same happens.

It doesnt seem related to the delay between prefetch and actual use, but it seems to happen for the tiles on `c` and `d` subdomains... whose link appear last in the html.

Would that be a limit of the browser ?

When I add a 5th domain (that is not related to Stamen) preconnect link *before* the Stamen links, it doesnt change anything about this issue (and the `b` domain is still prefetched and preconnected for both first and last images on that subdomain)

I would like the initial preconnect or prefetch link to be used for *all* later images on that same subdomain during the whole page load. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefetch as well as @font-face implementation is determined by the browser. It can be thought of as a heads up to the browser that it is going to need these resources soon and then the browser decides how to handle the heads-up. In other words, they are "resource hints."

**dns-prefetch, preconnect, prefetch**, are all heads up you **"should"** get these resources. While **preload** would be the **must-get** this resource with the caveat of load and render the page first. preload is not a load before or as a requirement to load the page ... it is still **a hint** or telling the browser, "you will need this to use the page," which the browser may not do if it so decides - expect a lazy-loading of these "must get" resources.

If the browser say has many tabs open and is using to many resources already it may decide that the best experience it can give the user is to not take the hint so as to not slow down the system.

If you truly must download these resources it can be done with javascript, aservice worker, or part of the tools service workers use. But this is trending into stackoverflow territory. It can be done but I don't know that second guessing the browser is going to be an improvement.

```
const myImage = new Image(100, 200);
myImage.src = 'picture.jpg';
```

The service worker uses the cache promise, which can be used outside of the service worker.

```
caches.open('static').then(cache => cache.addAll(["/lens.png","/new.png"]))
```

The cache API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache is part of the service worker API but it can add to the cache from the main thread. It is not exclusive to a registered service worker, it can cache content without registration. Although it can not handle fetch events outside of the service worker.

### A service worker

The service workers itself is part of the progressive web application tools that allow a site to work offline. It is registered as a man in the middle and can only be used within a limited scope of the site itself using https security for what should be obvious reasons. You can not scope to a CDN! but you may find it useful if you place the content on your own site.

FYI the service worker does not require web content to be a web application. Notifications are a service worker event. Although I don't like all these websites asking if I want to receive notifications.

It must be registered with an OK given by the user, and runs in its own thread as an event driven script.

```
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js", {
    scope: "/",
  });
```

Then caches all content needed to run the website/webapp without an internet connect. listens for fetch events and decides if the cache will handle the event, or can make an internet request for the resource. So basically you can use the web content without an internet connection.

However, I noticed you need resources from a different domain. You are using a CDN. Obviously a service worker is not going to deliever resources from a different domain as a man in the middle.

Comment: This is a detailed explanation... but i feel it doesnt answer my question.
<link> tags trigger the preconnect fine, as shown on the screenshot, but the issue is that preconnected DNS are only used for the images in the first set of map tiles, but not for half of the images in the 2nd set of map tiles.
- Why doesnt the browser use an allready preconnected domain for the 2nd image when the connection is done and has been used fine for the first image ? 
- How can the allready preconnected domains and connections be used for all of the ressources that can benefit them and not only one time ?

Comment: I can not justify the reason why the browser has implemented the feature in the way they have.  I'm more of a cynic of googleplex than an apologist of googleplex.  What we as webmasters can do is drop down to javascript if the implementation does not suit our use case. The problem is not your coding, which is consistent with the standard.

Comment: That connects your answer to my issue. Thanks.